# Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))

Tags: asp.net

Code snippet :

```
  public static void SendEmail(string _ToEmail, string _Subject, string _EmailBody)
{
    oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem email = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)(oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
    email.Recipients.Add(_ToEmail);
    email.Subject = _Subject;
    email.Body = _EmailBody;
    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)email).Send();
}
```

this method works well when i tested it in another project(located in file system) but when tried to test it from IIS (virtual site);It throw this exception in line : email.Recipients.Add(_ToEmail);

any help will be appreciated

P.S. the ASPNET account has the administrator permission

thanks in advance.

Comment: `E_ABORT` is a generic error, you need to look for docs to understand its meaning. But, in this case, Outlook is an interactive application, using from a server is not a good idea. There are better ways to send an email (including core framework types). You're getting the error on the first method call into the automation object – I expect Outlook is failing to fully initialise because there is no configuration for it to use with the IIS Worker Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the reference is set in your web.config

Comment: To reference what exactly?